# Difference between Accessors and Mutators in JavaScript and Java

Tags: java, javascript, setter, getter

In a JavaScript Circle object, I could write something as follows:

```
var Circle = function (xCoordinate, yCoordinate, radius) {
    var x = xCoordinate,
        y = yCoordinate,
        r = radius;

    this.getX = function () {
        return x;
    }

    this.getY = function () {
        return y;
    }

    this.getRadius = function () {
        return r;
    }
}
```

Whereas in Java, I'd write the following:

```
public class Circle {
    private x, y, radius;

    public Circle(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, radius) {
        this.x = xCoordinate;
        this.y = yCoordinate;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    //and so on...
}
```

But I've seen production standard JavaScript code not even bother with accessors and mutators as shown in the first example, whereas in Java, it would be odd not to have getters and setters as in the second.

1. When am I supposed to use getters / setters in JavaScript?
2. Would it be too much of a strain on resources if I adamantly used getters and setters for all of my JavaScript constructor objects?

Comment: Check this article [link](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for providing accessors and mutators is for encapsulation purposes, not so that it will look right. This is object orientation. If you wish to apply the same principle to JavaScript, then do that.

Answer (score 0):

In java, Accessor method are used to access the property of an object. In other words, Accessor method act as a mediator to access the private variable by methods outside a class or some other class. Hence, we can say that accessor method is used to provide encapsulation. The Accessor method is also known as a **getter** method.

In java, Mutator method are used to change the properties of an object. In other words, Mutator method initialize or change the value of the instance variable of the class or a private variable of the class. Hence, we can say that mutator method is used to provide encapsulation. A Mutator method is also known as a **Setter** method or Modifiers.